# Question about a build; Paladin Monk or Fighter Monk?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, player-characters

I plan on making either a Paladin Monk or Fighter Monk, one that uses a Longsword/Battleaxe, depending on the race I choose (with my main two races being Mountain Dwarf and Human Variant for their decent traits, and that feat is looking mighty fine if I can get the Mariner Fighter Style or Defensive Duelist).

At the current level of my campaign, I am level 3 almost level 4 (literally just 600 xp left to go).

How would I go about doing this at 3rd or fourth level without sacrificing such important things unique to my character (I will put a description of him at the end of the question so that I can get different ideas for how I can flavor my Martial Artist/Warrior)?

I plan on capping Fighter at 11-15, while the monk is going to be 5-9, gaining 9 Ki points with 3 attacks and, if I so choose, the ability to attack 8 times single turn if I activated both Flurry of Blows and Action Surge.

A question I also have is if I can flavor my Flurry of Blows as my character doing a normal attack with his weapon, doing the entire effect of the weapon and, as a bonus action, attacking with my weapon without any magical properties and only changing Unarmed attack to a Slashing Attack. I think this may break the game, but if it is entirely possible, I wish to incorporate the Versatile property into my Flurry of Blows, making my Two-Handed Unarmed attacks deal 1d8 Slashing Damage instead of 1d6, though I understand that that would be a bit.
How do I say? Broken for purposes of things like Great Weapon Fighting and the such. Unless I take up the Fighting Style Unarmed Fighting, which grants me the ability to deal a 1d8 if I am not wielding anything in my off-hand (basically, 2-handing a Fist with the Fist equal to a level 11 monk's fist)).

Character concept (For idea purposes): A soldier who was originally Viking's child raised by a monastery of monks, wandering the lands for a crime he never committed.

He will be most likely a Dwarf or Human, maybe an elf if I want to play into the Norse Mythical Elves. Should I play an elf, it will either be a Wood Elf or Ljósálfar, a subrace I found on DM's Guild.
I only have the sample file for the Ljósálfar, so, if you want the link to the PDF, here it is. https://www.dmsguild.com/product/258262/The-Ljosalfar-Light-Elves-A-Playable-Race-for-5th-Edition

Comment: Since your link to dmsguild pointed to D&D 5e as your system, I added the tag.  This question may need a little editing to fit the stack model, though. First of all, have you talked to your DM about this build?  If not, you have a bunch of rulings the DM has to make. Secondly, what problem are you trying to solve? Are you asking for which race fits the concept better, or which class combination meets a certain objective.  And that leads us to: what is your objective for this build.  You are at 3d level: what class are you now?  Monk? Fighter? Paladin?  We need details to give you an answer.

Comment: I've removed the link you posted to the file on your disk. We cannot download things from your computer like that.